# Apply a function to each column of a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of numbers going from 1 to 13 (each number is a location). As the index, I have set a timeline representing timesteps of 2 min during 24h (720 rows). Each column represents a single person. So I have columns of locations along 24h in 2 min timesteps.

I am trying to convert this numbers to binary (if it's a 13, I want a 1, and otherwise a 0). But when I try to apply the function I get an error:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
df = pd.read_csv("dataset_belgium/all_patterns_2MINS.csv", encoding="utf-8")
df = df.transpose()

df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)


timeline = []
for timestep in range(len(df.index)):
    time = timedelta(seconds=timestep*2*60)
    time = str(time)
    timeline.append(time)


tl = pd.DataFrame(timeline)
tl.columns = ['timeline']

df=df.join(tl, how='left')

df = df.set_index('timeline')
#df.drop(['0:00:00'])

def to_binary(element):
    if element == 13:
        element = 1
    else:
        element = 0
    return element

binary_df = df.apply(to_binary)
```

Also I would like to eliminate the 1st row, the one of index ('0:00:00'), since it doesn't contain numbers from 1 to 13.
​
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say in the title, you apply the function to each column of the data frame. So what you call `element` within the function is actually a whole column. That's why the line `if element == 13:` raises an error. Python doesn't know what it would mean for a whole column to be equal to one number. One straightforward solution would be to use a for loop:

```py
def to_binary(column):
    for element in column:
        if element == 13:
            element = 1
        else:
            element = 0
    return column
```

However, this would still not solve the more basic issue that the function doesn't actually change anything with lasting effect, because it uses only local variables.

An easy alternative approach is to use the pandas `replace` method, which allows you to explicitly replace arbitrary values with other ones:

```py
df.replace([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], 
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  1], 
           inplace=True)
```

To delete the first row, you can use `df = df[1:]`.